# gradle "universalApk true" doesn't build me an apk with all the mentioned ABIs

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I'm using android studio 2.1.2 and gradle 2.12, 
with the following gradle.build script:

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

After the build, it generates the following APKs.

- project-armeabi-v7a-debug-unaligned.apk
- project-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk
- project-universal-debug-unaligned.apk
- project-universal-debug.apk
- project-x86-debug-unaligned.apk
- project-x86-debug.apk
- project-x86_64-debug-unaligned.apk
- project-x86_64-debug.apk

However, it seems the `project-universal-*.apk` doesn't contain the x86 and x86_64 support I want. It was not able to install on my x86_64 emulator. (which the `project-x86_64-debug.apk` works well)

```
$ adb install project-universal-debug.apk
[100%] /data/local/tmp/project-universal-debug.apk
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/project-universal-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]
```

And I also check it by the `aapt` command: (not sure it's the right way)

```
$aapt dump badging project-universal-debug.apk  | grep native-code
native-code: 'armeabi' 'armeabi-v7a'
```

What can I do the have the universal APK for all the ABIs from `include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a'`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the complete list of abis? This worked for me:

`include 'arm', 'arm-v7a', 'arm64', 'mips', 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a'`